# Running flutter app in vscode and get this error Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

i'm currently facing the problem in running my flutter app in physical device(phone). i'm using android studio 4 and vscode. The error message is below.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TECNO B1f in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to find target with hash string 'android-29' in: C:\Users\Kitsson\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest 4 methods to solve this issue , try one after another until it works for you :

1. Open terminal - run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`. Just accept all and it should work, if it dosen't then skip to next step.
2. adding `buildToolsVersion` in `android => app => build.gradle`

`android { compileSdkVersion 29 buildToolsVersion "29.0.0" ... ... }`

3. This often happens when you have something in your dependency that require internet like firebase. Just **turn on your internet or wifi** .
4. If none of them works then turn off developer option and turn it on again by pressing build number 7 times, this will revoke all usb debugging autherisation and ask whether to trust your developing machine , press yes and you will be good to go